# Configuring Supervisor for Daphne (Django Channels)

Tags: nginx, production-environment, supervisord, django-channels, daphne

I have created a web application with Django Channels which I face problems with while trying to set up with Supervisor system.

To start with, the application locally works well.

Remotely (I use an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS), when run with a command `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 mysite.asgi:application` it also works well.

However, I cannot make it work with Supervisor. I follow instructions from the official Django Channels docs (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html) and therefore I have:

- nginx config file:

  ```
  upstream channels-backend {
      server localhost:8000;
  }

  server {
      server_name www.example.com;

      keepalive_timeout 5;
      client_max_body_size 1m;

      access_log /home/ubuntu/django_app/logs/nginx-access.log;
      error_log /home/ubuntu/django_app/logs/nginx-error.log;

      location /static/ {
          alias /home/ubuntu/django_app/mysite/staticfiles/;
      }

      location / {
          try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
      }

      location @proxy_to_app {
          proxy_pass http://channels-backend;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      }

      listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.example.com;

      if ($host = www.example.com) {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      } # managed by Certbot

      return 404; # managed by Certbot
  }
  ```
- Supervisor config file:

  ```
  [fcgi-program:asgi]

  socket=tcp://localhost:8000

  directory=/home/ubuntu/django_app/mysite

  command=/home/ubuntu/django_app/venv/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers mysite.asgi:application

  numprocs=4

  process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

  autostart=true
  autorestart=true

  stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/django_app/logs/supervisor_log.log
  redirect_stderr=true
  ```

When set this way, the webpage does not work (504 Gateway Time-out). In the Supervisor log file I see:

```
2018-11-14 14:48:21,511 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2018-11-14 14:48:21,516 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2018-11-14 14:48:21,517 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2018-11-14 14:48:22,015 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2018-11-14 14:48:22,025 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2018-11-14 14:48:22,026 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1416' -> b'/run/daphne/daphne0.sock.lock'
2018-11-14 14:48:22,091 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne2.sock
2018-11-14 14:48:22,096 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2018-11-14 14:48:22,097 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2018-11-14 14:48:22,135 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne3.sock
2018-11-14 14:48:22,152 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2018-11-14 14:48:22,153 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2018-11-14 14:48:22,237 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2018-11-14 14:48:22,241 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2018-11-14 14:48:22,242 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne3.sock
2018-11-14 14:48:22,242 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1419' -> b'/run/daphne/daphne3.sock.lock'
2018-11-14 14:48:22,252 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne2.sock
2018-11-14 14:48:22,252 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1420' -> b'/run/daphne/daphne2.sock.lock'
```

etc.

Please note that in the Supervisor command the Daphne process is invoked in another way (with other set of parameters) than I run it before - instead of parameters for address and port, there are parameters for socket and file descriptor (about which I do not know much at all). I suspect that it is the reason of the encountered error.

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

The relevant packages versions:

```
channels==2.1.2
channels-redis==2.2.1
daphne==2.2.1
Django==2.1.2
```

EDIT:

When I create empty files for socket files (which are present in command for Daphne in the Supervisor config file), ie. `/run/daphne/daphne0.sock`, `/run/daphne/daphne1.sock`, etc., then the log file states the following:

```
2018-11-15 10:24:38,289 INFO     Starting server at fd:fileno=0, unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2018-11-15 10:24:38,290 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2018-11-15 10:24:38,280 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2018-11-15 10:24:38,458 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
2018-11-15 10:24:38,475 INFO     Configuring endpoint unix:/run/daphne/daphne0.sock
2018-11-15 10:24:38,476 CRITICAL Listen failure: Couldn't listen on any:b'/run/daphne/daphne0.sock': [Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

Question: should these files not be empty? What should they include?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. Was you able to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabio's answer, with replacing the file descriptor parameter for the endpoint parameter, presents a quick workaround for this problem (which appeared to be a bug in the Daphne code).

However, the fix in Daphne repository was quickly committed so that the original instructions work well.

As a side note (for people still getting critical listen failures which I wrote about in the original question), please be sure that the physical location for socket files (`/run/daphne/` in my case) is accessible - I spent too much time just to discover that simply creating the `daphne` folder in `/run` catalog does the job (even though I run everything with `sudo`)... For precautionary measures one may consider redirecting the socket files to another folder, e.g. `/tmp` which does let creating a directory without `sudo` permission.

Comment: I am still getting the same error as your question do you have idea

Comment: 2019-02-09 02:29:03,681 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2019-02-09 02:29:03,681 INFO     Configuring endpoint fd:fileno=0
2019-02-09 02:29:03,715 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
this is what am getting

Comment: all socket files are created in the run folder

Comment: i was able fix the issue

Comment: I create `daphne` folder in `/run/`, then everything work well.

Comment: @herock where is the /run/ present?

Comment: @NabeelAyub well, the `/` is the root directory and there you should find the `run` folder. But I believe it may differ with different versions of Linux (if you happen to have a very old one it might not be there at all, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-run-filesystem).

Comment: @MidhunMohan  How did you fix with [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket  error?

Answer (score 3):

In the supervisor ASGI config file, in the following line

`command=/home/ubuntu/django_app/venv/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers mysite.asgi:application`

replace `--fd 0` with `--endpoint fd:fileno=0`.

Issue: https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/234